# Check a value with encrypted field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Codeigniter encrypt library for data encryption and store it on db,but now i want to check a value exist or not in this table.

I have 3 fields in table which are encrypted,if I give same value it will store different string in field every time, so how can I check them my value ?

Table

[image]

controller code

```
$result = $this->Home_model->check_mail($this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('email')));
```

model code

```
function check_mail($email){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('enquiry');
    $this->db->where('email',$email);        
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Comment: add your code that you have tried and your database

Comment: Other then building A.I in the PHP code to geuss the encrypting in the future? You can't most likely you are looking for hashing (SHA256, SHA512 for example) instead of a encryption which gives a different result for each time you execute like MCrypt, Blowfish ? ..  But you also might be looking for a `password_verify()` hard to say without user case, example code and table structure.